# When building an Atom Package, how do you show a list in a popup menu?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

I'm building an Atom Package and I'm trying to show a list of items to the user. The user can search through those items and pick one. I'm trying to make something that *looks* like the menu below.

[image]
<sub>(source: [github-camo.com](https://i.github-camo.com/66a8b9f48e16131197cca2ca3ffebde9e8679c99/68747470733a2f2f662e636c6f75642e6769746875622e636f6d2f6173736574732f3637313337382f323234313335342f32393038623736382d396363642d313165332d396461312d6131313735336330343935642e706e67))</sub>

This is sort-of like the Command Palette, except I want all items are from my package. I don't want to modify the Command Palette.

My package works basically like: You press Command+R, and this list-menu pops up with about 100 different options. The user then picks one of those options. I am not interested in the `atom.commands.add` API -- I'm not sure how to do this and I've looked hard at the API and searched online with no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developers of Atom provide the [`atom-select-list`](https://github.com/atom/atom-select-list) Etch component for this purpose.

**Example:**

```
const SelectList = require('atom-select-list')

const usersSelectList = new SelectList({
  items: ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol']
})
document.body.appendChild(usersSelectList.element)
```

Unfortunately, the documentation is scarce. I found it useful to [take a look](https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=atom-select-list&type=Code) how others implemented it.

Comment: Dude -- thanks a ton. I couldn't find that and I spent a good chunk of my day searching documentation. I thought it would be part of the core API.